# TypeScript pass method parameter values dynamically

Tags: typescript

I need to pass some method parameters using a loop. Something like this:

```
array.forEach(element => {
    // Pseudo Code.
    // Add the parameter value to the method call on each loop.
    myMethod().parameters.append(element)
});


// OR -->
let params;
array.forEach(element => {
    // Pseudo Code.
    params.append(element);
});
myMethod(params)
```

Is this possible in Typescript/JavaScript?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you going to invoke `myMethod()` multiple times with each time having an additional parameter?

Comment: @unional I don't need to do it like shown above. I have a function callback and I need to add the parameters dynamically. Sometimes I just need to pass a single object into the method I am calling, other times I have multiple parameters I need to pass. For example, myMethod() above may take myMethod(someObject) or it may take myMethod(true, false, "some string"). myMethod() is dynamic and not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is the fn.apply():

```
myMethod.apply(this, array)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp